# Troubleshoot GStreamer pipeline freezing

Tags: c, gstreamer, freeze

Currently I working on android app which will play and record video form remote source

My pipeline looks like this

```
videotestsrc do-timestamp=true ! videoscale add-borders=false ! capsfilter ! videoflip method=0 ! tee name=split 
    split. ! queue ! videoconvert ! glupload ! glshader ! autovideosink async=false !
    split. ! queue ! identity drop-probability=0 ! videoconvert ! timeoverlay ! x264enc key-int-max=10 ! h264parse ! splitmuxsink location=/sdcard/test-%d.mp4
```

Only problem stat I see in logs

```
video_buffer_pool_set_config:<videobufferpool1> no caps in config
```

I'm not asking to fix my pipeline, I just wanna understand it there any common algorithm how to troubleshoot this kind of freeze?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best tool you'll have is probably the `GST_DEBUG_BIN_TO_DOT_FILE` macro, in gstdebugutils.h.  It'll show your pipeline and the state of each element.  It does require you to set the `GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR` environment variable.

Then you run a command like this to create a PNG or some other image file from the dot.

`dot -Tpng pipeline.dot -o pipeline.png`

On our desktop systems we usually package all this up into a command we can add to our programs.  I'm not sure what your best route is in Android.  Perhaps there are some additional APIs there that can help.

After you identify your problem elements, use the `GST_DEBUG` environment variable to add additional logging.  For example if you have an `x264enc` error, use:

`GST_DEBUG=2,x264enc:5`

That'll set the logging level to error for everything except x264enc which will be debug level.

Also if you run a debugger you can usually look through all the threads and find which element is hanging.